# Does the dicothomy Cardio vs Strenght training even exits?

Tags: strength, cardio

Experts have told us that a combination of Cardio and Strength is best for health, however I haven't been able to find why is exercise is divided in Cardio and strength? Does every type of physical activity fit into Cardio and Strength dichotomy or are there other type of exercises?

Answer (score 0):

Cardio's benefit comes from sustained and prolonged elevated heart rate with continuous activity. The result of which allows you to sustain an activity for longer times.

Strength/hypertrophy's benefit comes from short intense bouts of pushing or pulling against a high resistance. The result of which allows you to move or manipulate heavier and denser objects.

People might say that resistance training gives the same benefits as a HIIT style workout. This is inaccurate. HIIT workouts should never have the heart rate go back to baseline. The HR should always be between moderately high to extremely high. In contrast, the HR in a strength training program is usually between baseline to moderately high.

There is of course an overlap between the two. Cycling up a hill forces your legs to push against a heavy resistance. Over time your legs will become stronger from it, but the effect isn't as acute than if you did a strength focused leg exercise. Likewise, a long set of 15 reps leg press is going to elevate your heart rate significantly, but it will go back down to near baseline as soon as the sets over and you're resting.  You'll get some cardio benefit from it, but the effect won't be as acute as a dedicated sustained cardio session.

There are workouts that attempt to mix the two. Crossfit and bootcamp style workouts force athletes to do a mix of both in which they lift a light resistance continuously for a very prolonged time. However, that would still be considered "cardio" because it is not a very efficient way to build strength or muscle. The most dedicated athletes who do those still do strength building workout and a dedicated cardio workout to supplement the main sport.

Comment: I'd say different metabolisms and the effects of training on Type I vs. Type II fibres might play a role as well?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Yeah, but does there need that much detail when simply asking what the difference between a "cardio workout" and a "strength workout" is?